# Is this series absolutely convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$ absolutely converge?

The index n=1 kept me hanging too. This is an item I saw in one of my books. Isn't the series wrong as the first term of the series will have a 0 in the denominator?

Comment: OOOOooopss.. I posted a wrong question. I meant to ask if it is absolutely convergent. Im having trouble testing the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix any mistakes in it. Just click "edit" in the lower left side of it (under the tags).

Comment: You are right that the sum should start at $n=2$ (or some integer greater than 1).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does converge (use the alternating series test). It also converges absolutely since
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n\log^2n}\le\int_2^\infty\frac1{x\log^2x}\mathrm dx=\frac1{\log2}.
$$

Comment: @gki You're welcome!